# Is it bad practice to allow dots in SVN tags/branches' names?

Tags: svn, tags, branch, version-control

In my SVN repository `tag`s are listed by version where name contains dots. e.g. `0.10` or `0.12.1`

`branches` are named like `proj-0.24-rc`

In the same time, for example in [Mono project](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/source/branches/mono-2-6-4/) branches has not dots.

Is it some practice to avoid dots? Could it be treated like extension delimiter (by web server where repository is been served), etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think many large projects create tags with dots/periods, so I don't think there is anything wrong with it (at least not from a Subversion standpoint).

If you have some special software that is being thrown off by the periods... Then I guess that is another story.

Comment: I agree - we do that all the time with branches and release tags.  They're simply named 2.3.0.1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for SVN identifiers which make problems on some platforms. For example, Windows can't deal with names only differing in *capitalization*. Also certain characters (`:`, `/`, `\` etc.) are *reserved on certain platforms* and shouldn't be used.

I'm not aware of any platform... well, besides CPM or DOS, that is, so let's say: I'm not aware of any *relevant* platform having trouble with arbitrary dots in file system identifiers, so I think these are not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is not a technical limitation.

I have been using dots for branch and tag names for ages and never encountered any problems with any of the SVN clients I have used.